# Not able to update model in loopback

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, loopbackjs, loopback

I am using updatingAll method in loopback but it is not working I am not able to understand the reason

I have written something like this

```
let data = {
      isActive: false
    };

      myModel
          .updateAll(data, {
            id: {
              inq: questionIds
            },
          });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of parameters in updateAll seems to be incorrect. From [documentation](http://apidocs.loopback.io/loopback/#persistedmodel-updateall):

> PersistedModel.updateAll([where], data, callback)

Also, it seems a callback function is **required**.

> Callback function called with (err, info) arguments. Required.

So your call should look like this:

```
let data = {
    isActive: false
};
myModel.updateAll({
    id: {
        inq: questionIds
    },
}, data, (err, info) => null); //might want to add error checking to callback function
```